# REST API design - optional request parameters

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, design-patterns

I've written this request mapping to access a ticket by it's id:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/tickets/{ticketId}")
   @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<List<TicketResponse>> getTicketsById(@PathVariable("ticketId") final Long ticketId
```

I'm planning to add multiple query parameters to support filtering such as ticketType, ticketStatus. REST API users should have options to filter on any or all of the query parameters.

What are the REST API design principles to achieve this ? Should I add new request parameters to support the filtering like below ? :

```
@GetMapping(path = "/tickets/{ticketId}")
   @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<List<TicketResponse>> getTicketsById(@PathVariable("ticketId") final Long ticketId, @RequestParam("ticketType") final String ticketType, @RequestParam("ticketStatus") final String ticketStatus)
```

Is there a Spring design pattern for this scenario ? The Java builder pattern could be used where parameter an attribute of a QueryParameter object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1. Either you put all your RequestParams as method parameters, but with `required=false`, like @AmitKumar wrote. Example: `@RequestParam(name="ticketType", required = false) String ticketType`
2. Put all these parameters into a, let's say FilterDTO and have that as a parameter (`FilterDTO filter`). Spring will make sure to populate its fields with your RequestParams . Just put your ticketType and other parameters into the DTO as fields, and they will be optional. Example: `public ResponseEntity<List<TicketResponse>> getTicketsById(@PathVariable("ticketId") ong ticketId, FilterDto filter){}`

Comment: In the second scenario, the HTTP method should be POST and not GET.

Comment: @BhawnaJoshi Why do you think it needs to be a POST?

Comment: Regarding the second solution, does all of the DTO fields need to be populated with values? I have a class with like 15 fields which 11 of them are optional. Am I supposed to overload the constructor with all the combinations of optional parameters?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make parameter as an optional. you need to add required=false.

```
public ResponseEntity<List<TicketResponse>> getTicketsById(@PathVariable("ticketId") final Long ticketId, @RequestParam(name="ticketType", required=false) final String ticketType, @RequestParam(name="ticketStatus",required=false) final String ticketStatus)
```